# How to shrink html elements to fit in fixed-size div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div tag `<div id="preview"></div>` with a fixed width and height, and in the preview I'd like to display some html: h1, h2, p, block quotes, lists, all shrunk down so the entire chunk of html fits inside the preview, perfectly scaled and proportioned. How would I go about it? Thanks!

Comment: Please show us your HTML, and, ideally, a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/). Explain the difficulties you're having, and what you want that you don't seem to be getting.

Comment: It's clear from the question what he's asking. A live demo is nice but not required.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use CSS's `zoom` property:

```
#preview { 
    zoom: 0.5; 
    /* For Firefox */
    -moz-transform: scale(0.5); 
    -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After more research it seems that the iframe is more appropriate for displaying html: instead of supplying an external link to a web page, you can load the iframe with raw html directly. Also you can embed a stylesheet in the iframe and the stylesheet won't affect the rest of your site. Perfect for themes. You can see the jsfiddle [here.](http://jsfiddle.net/ExPraliteMonk/Cfjg9)

**HTML**

```
<textarea id="editor"><p>This is plain html to keep it simple. In my 
application, this would be Markdown text and converted to html by a 
Markdown converter in javascript.</p></textarea>

<iframe id="preview"></iframe>​​​
```

**JavaScript**

```
var html = document.getElementById('editor').value;
head = '<style type="text/css">#inner {color: blue; margin: auto; zoom: 0.6; -moz-transform: scale(0.6); -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;}</style>';     
var body = '<div id="inner">' + html + '</div>';
var preview = document.getElementById('preview').contentWindow.document;
preview.head.innerHTML = head;
preview.body.innerHTML = body;​
```

**CSS**

```
#editor, #preview {
    height: 300px;
    width: 200px;
}

textarea {
    resize: none;
}​
```